# Looker Studio adds "LIMIT 20000000" to BigQuery reports. Need insights on this limit

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I've generated a revenue table categorizing data by date, app, and category using BigQuery as the data source.

When accessing the report through Looker Studio, I noticed that the query executed includes the "LIMIT 20000000."

​​​​SELECT * FROM (
SELECT clmn2_, clmn1_, SUM(clmn5_) AS clmn100000_ FROM ( SELECT * FROM ( SELECT t0.app_name AS clmn2_, t0.revenue AS clmn5_, t0.transaction_date AS clmn1_ FROM table_name t0 ) WHERE ((clmn1_ >= DATE "2023-11-01") AND (clmn1_ <= DATE "2023-11-07") AND (clmn2_ <> "null") ) ) GROUP BY clmn2_, clmn1_
) LIMIT 20000000​

Why is this limit automatically added, and is there a method to regulate or modify this limit in the context of a report linked to a BigQuery data source?